# How to change image height in RNotebook

Tags: rnotebook

I want to increase the height of an image that is generated by RNotebook. When I use `fig.height` chunk option, it merely decreases font sizes and marker sizes, but picture remains the same. For example:

[image: original plot (plot(iris)]

and here is result with `fig.height=3`:

[image: plot(iris) with fig.height=3 specified]

How would I actually change height of the output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [R Markdown: The Definitive Guide](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/notebook.html), by default,

> Plots emitted from a chunk are rendered to match the width of the editor at the time the chunk was executed. The height of the plot is determined by the golden ratio.

Specifying `fig.size` would not change aspect ratio: you actually change the whole size of the picture (width and height are changed proportionally), but when RNotebook shows it to you it rescales it automatically to fit editor window. So you don't see a difference other than change of size of fonts, etc.

To actually produce taller image, you have to specify `fig.asp`, like `fig.asp=1.2`.

[image: plot(iris) with fig.asp=1.2 and fig.width=3]